# ASP.NET MVC 3 and Global Filter Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject-2, ninject.web

Hello am an trying to implement a global filter with injection.
The filter looks like this.

```
public class WikiFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private IWikiService service;

    public WikiFilter(IWikiService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        !!!Code here!!
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And i have attached the filter with injection the following way in my global.asax.

```
      public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication, 
        IAuthenticationApplication<User>
        {
            protected void Application_Start()
            {
                Ninject();
                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            }

            private void Ninject()
            {
                // Create Ninject DI kernel
                IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

                kernel.Bind<DataContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
                kernel.Bind<IWikiRepository>().To<WikiRepository>();
                kernel.Bind<IWikiService>().To<WikiService>();

                // Global filters
                kernel.BindFilter<WikiFilter>(FilterScope.Global, 0);

                DependencyResolver.SetResolver
                  (new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
            }
        }
```

But for some reason is the filter never fired when the application runs, have i not implemented it correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend you using the `~/App_Start/NinjectMVC3.cs` file to configure the Ninject kernel:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppName.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(AppName.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Stop")]

namespace AppName.App_Start
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Mvc;
    using Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax;

    public static class NinjectMVC3
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<DataContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IWikiRepository>().To<WikiRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IWikiService>().To<WikiService>();
            kernel.BindFilter<WikiFilter>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

and the Global.asax stays unchanged. By the way that's the default setup when you install the Ninject.MVC3 NuGet package.

Comment: Even if this worked I still wonder why his original solution didn't.

Comment: @Darin if you added the filter via ninject, does that mean you do not need to register this filter in FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)?